# programmably create picturebox inside panel

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Hey all i have created a panel that i want to place a lot of pictureboxes inside of. I will be pulling pictures from the "my pictures" folder. I am wanting to have 3 pictureboxes per row.

My current code is this:

```
Dim newPictureBox As New PictureBox

newPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg")
newPictureBox.Visible = True
newPictureBox.Top = 0 'needed calulation here for each picturebox
newPictureBox.Left = 0 'needed calulation here for each picturebox
newPictureBox.Width = 536
newPictureBox.Height = 338
newPictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
Panel1.Controls.Add(newPictureBox)
```

That does just fine for the first picturebox inside the panel but i will be looping an unknown number of pictures that need pictureboxes to go with it. I know the next picturebox should have a *Left* value of 545 but i am unsure of how to calcualte that out? Then the *top* calculations for the second row, third row, etc...

What would the process be for getting the correct *Top, Left* coordinates for each picturebox so that it only has 3 pictureboxes in each row?

Comment: `newLeft = (Width * N) + myDesiredMargin`...pass 0, 1 or 2 as N to the procedure making the pictureboxes to calculate.

Comment: Well, use a FlowLayoutPanel instead so you don't have to bother.

Comment: @HansPassant how would i populate the pictures in a row then?

Comment: Have you found the FlowDirection property yet?  Try this first with the designer so you can't miss it.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, left to right but how do i place each picture on it without telling it where to go (top, left)? Wont it just stack each picturebox on top of each other?